# Python color traces in plotly using groupby

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Group   Dtime         Value        
Grp1    2015-01-01    1261.406773       
Grp1    2015-01-02    1252.660231       
Grp1    2015-01-03    1223.076426
Grp2    2015-01-01    1214.402352
Grp2    2015-01-02    1422.532532
Grp2    2015-01-03    1262.990213
```

How can I use Plotly to plot a timeseries of [Value] where the color of the trace is determined by [Group]?

I've tried setting the `color= df.Group` but this only seems to work in Plotly express but I need this for plotly.

I've also tried manually splitting the df up by Group and plotting each Group as a separate trace, but this seems to just use whatever the final color I set last for the whole plot. This feels like it should be something relatively simple to do so am I missing something?

Comment: Try this: `import plotly.express as px;
fig = px.line(df,x='Dtime',y='Value',color='Group');
fig.update_xaxes(dtick='1D');
fig.show()`

Comment: Can't use Plotly.express in this circumstance

Comment: Did you actually run the code in my comment? What is different from what you expect?